# Set an Error message for custom validator

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I have custom validator apllied to many comboboxes in different tabs of application. Its is performing the same validation for all the comboboxes. The only difference is for ecah combobox the custom validator should return a different error messagae. How can error message be specified...?...like some error property in mxml or by somehow passing the error message as parameters to custom validator class.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to set the [errorString](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#errorString) property on any UIComponent.

Comment: @J_A_X: The code in mxml to apply validator on combobox is : <flexScript:cmb1Validator id="cmb1_Validator" source="{cmb1}" property="text"/>   The validation logic is written in Custom validator class cmbValidator. But here in mxml no propety like errorString comes....:(

Comment: By the UIComponent, I mean the actual visual components, like TextInput, ComboBox, RadioButton, etc...

Comment: Wait, my bad.  I forgot that errorString is to just show a red box and tip in the component, but doesn't do validation.  I don't think I understand your problem, you should have one validator per component, and each validator can have it's own error message.

Comment: @J_A_X:Thanks for your response, but as i mentioned in the post i dont want to have one validator per component as it will lead in making a number of custom validators with the same logic, just with one line of error different in each validator, resulting in lot of code  redundancy.

Comment: I've had that problem before.  Unfortunately, this is how validators work and there's no way around that.  Either have multiple validators *or* have a class (a factory) create all the validators for you.  From there you only need to specify which UIComponent it needs to relate to and what's the error that should be associated with it.

Comment: is it feasible for you to give any code example for implementing it using class factory?

Comment: Sorry, I can't.  It's not my IP.  I'm sure you can figure it out.